# PPA hosting packages not built on launchpad build farm

Tags: ppa, launchpad, build

Is it possible to build the deb packages in house and then upload the binaries to launchpad PPA, instead of uploading the source package and let it build by the build farm ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No it's not possible, as Launchpad only accepts source package uploads for reasons of trust - people need to be able to have the source to what was built, and you cannot put proprietary software into PPAs.

Comment: And what about xswat PPA with nvidia binary drivers?

Comment: @Extender: Most likely a "source package" where the specified compile rules is about putting the provided binary bits in place.